# Changing SSRS parameter values after the report is run. Is this possible?

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameters

I'm trying to change SSRS parameter values after the report is run. Is this possible? Reason is that I have seven params with two set before running the report. The user can then click on a URL value from the report list to go to a drilldown report. Depending on the selection the user clicks the remaining five params will have different values, but I don't know how to change them to match where the use clicks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **Go to Report** action, you would add the parameters and set them to whatever field, parameter or other value that you want.

If you are using **Go to URL** you need to add them into the URL text string.

At the end of the URL for the report, add the &rs:Command=Render then add an ampersand, your parameter name, and an equals sign. Then escape out of the string and add your value. Here's a sample that passes fields, parameters and hard coded values to the drill down report parameters.

```
="javascript:void window.open('" & Globals!ReportServerUrl & "?"
& Globals!ReportFolder & "/ClaimsRecoveriesDetails&rs:Command=Render" 
& "&YYYYMM=" & CSTR(Fields!RECOVERY_YEAR.Value) & CSTR(Fields!RECOVERY_MONTH.Value)
& "&PARTICIPATION_TYPE=" & Parameters!PARTICIPATION_TYPE.Value
& "&ISRECOVERIESSUBMITTED=" & "YES" 
+ "&rs:Command=Render','_blank','resizeable=1,toolbar=0,status=0,menu=0,top=20,left=15,width=1500,height=700,scrollbars=1')"
```

The javascript is used to open a separate window for this one.

Here's some (lame) advice from Microsoft: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-2017